# New .Net Core Library Serialization Attributes Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core

I'm trying to extract some classes from an MVC project into their own .Net Core class library in the same solution. So far, I have added this class to the new class library:

```
[DataContract]
public class EmailStatusNotification
{
    [DataMember(Name = "nothing_interesting")]
    public string TestProp { get; set; }
}
```

`[DataContract]` displays an error :

> *Cannot apply attribute class `DataContract` because it is abstract.*

`[DataMember]` displays an error :

> *The type `Object` is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly `mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`.*

What is likely the cause of this? I have not removed any dependencies from the project.

Comment: Have you checked .NET framerowk's version you build against?

Comment: @m.rogalski Thanks, I just posted an answer to the question. This wasn't working for two days, and suddenly after repeating the process for the millionth time. Seems like the concept of "if you didn't fix it, it ain't fixed" doesn't apply in Microsoft's lovely ecosystem.

Answer (score 4):

I was running into the exact same problem with `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]`. It turns out that there was an extra assembly reference to `System.Runtime.Serialization` that was causing some ambiguity when trying to use the `DataContractAttribute`. Removing the assembly reference fixed the error. I suspect that one of the times you recreated the library you also cleared the references.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the class library in the exact same way for the 5th or 6th time and it miraculously started working. I'm almost positive that this was a bug/feature of Visual Studio, but I don't even know how to go about reporting it as it's so abstract.